# Animate ProgressBar content WPF with specific value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, progress-bar

I'm trying to develop a `ProgressBar` that fills accordingly to a value that I manually set to it. For example, I have this `ProgressBar`:

```
<ProgressBar Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="progressBar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="285" />
```

I have a button that increases the `ProgressBar` value in 10 units each time you press it, like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value += 10;
}
```

I want to animate that value change each time I click on it. I tried this:

```
Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
DoubleAnimation doubleanimation = new DoubleAnimation(200.0, duration);
progressBar1.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, doubleanimation);
```

But it goes from 0 to 100 value of the `ProgressBar`. How can I tell the animation to stop on a specific value, instead of going to 100%?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are actually animating the `Value` to a final value of 200 if you do th following:

```
DoubleAnimation doubleanimation = new DoubleAnimation(200.0, duration);
```

Instead change the first argument to the value you want to animate to. Your event handler should be like so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    DoubleAnimation doubleanimation = new DoubleAnimation(progressBar1.Value + 10, duration);
    progressBar1.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, doubleanimation);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`DoubleAnimation Constructor (Double, Duration)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558154.aspx) the first paramater is

> The destination value of the animation.

So change this

```
DoubleAnimation doubleanimation = new DoubleAnimation(200.0, duration);
```

to

```
DoubleAnimation doubleanimation = new DoubleAnimation(progressBar1.Value, duration);
```

Comment: `But it goes from 0 to 100 value of the ProgressBar. How can I tell the animation to stop on a specific value, instead of going to 100%?` My answer is just based on this question

Comment: Actually, if you didn't notice, they say the same thing.

Comment: (3 years later) @Cullub They don't, Bolu's answer is animated the value property from its original value to... its original value, it wont do anything

Comment: @Treycos Wow you're right.  I think they meant the same, but Bolu's answer should be `DoubleAnimation(progressBar1.Value + 10, ...` instead of just the current value.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, I found a solution in [this](http://bensprogrammingwork.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/progressbar-in-wpf.html) link. It explains how to fill `ProgressBar` value using a  `BackgroundWorker`.

I wrote this code:

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
    InitializeComponent();

    backgroundworker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundworker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    backgroundworker.DoWork += backgroundworker_DoWork;
    backgroundworker.ProgressChanged += backgroundworker_ProgressChanged;
}

private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    backgroundworker.CancelAsync();
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (backgroundworker.IsBusy == false)
    {
       backgroundworker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}

void backgroundworker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

void backgroundworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    if (worker != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            worker.ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }
}
```