# C# wpf, how to update a progressbar over 1 second

Tags: c#, wpf

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to have a progress bar "progress" (fill up) over 1 second.
I do NOT mean one update every one second, what I want is:

After 100 milliseconds, 10% progress

after 200ms, 20% progress

...
after 1000ms, 100% progress.

How does one do this?

Comment: You can use an `Animation` as shown in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594871/animate-progressbar-content-wpf-with-specific-value) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45737756/13085337

Answer (score 0):

```
await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
{
    for (int i = 10; i <= 100; i += 10)
    {
        yourprogressbar.Value = i;
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
});
```

You need to add `async` keyword on your method to be able to use `await`.